# What is the difference between these Javascript Promise chains?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm a beginner in JS and I have a question about Promises.

**Context:** I have a basic promise with 3 callbacks:

```
const calcul = (num1, num2) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const result = num1 * num2;
    if(result > 20000){
      resolve(result);
    }else{
      reject();
    }
  })
}

const fun1 = (result) => {
  console.log('Result: ' + result);
};

const fun2 = () => {
  console.log('Oups, error');
};

const fun3 = () => {
  console.log('Oups, another error');
};
```

**What is the difference between:**

```
calcul(300,9).then(fun1).catch(fun2);
```

and

```
calcul(300,9).then(fun1,fun2);
```

**What is the difference between:**

```
calcul(300,90).then(fun1).catch(fun2).then(() => {console.log("FINALLY")});
```

and

```
calcul(300,900).then(fun1).catch(fun2).finally(() => {console.log("FINALLY")});
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a `throw "something";` to `fun1`.

Answer (score 1):

So in the first case, the difference is that in the `catch`, you are handling the promise returned by `then` (which may just be an unhandled rejected promise from `calcul`, or a problem in the `then` handler) while in the `then(func,func)` one, you are handling either a successful promise returned by `calcul` or a rejected promise returned by `calcul`. Make sense?

In the second case a difference is that `then` would not be called if `catch` throws an error, while `finally` will be called always.

Comment: thanks for your help!